# Angularjs issue with ng-click on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, mobile, angularjs-ng-click

i've got a big performance issue.

I'm in a ng-repeat block (and i'm using track by id to improve performances).
In this block i'm generating the following dom:

1)button1A button1B
2)button2A button2B
3)button3A button3B
4)button4A button4B
5)button5A button5B
6)button6A button6B

There are some ng-show and ng-disabled in that page, on a variable that is set by ng-click on those buttons.

Performances are very poor.
On mobile we are using ng-mobile and\or fastclick for 300ms delay removing, but it seems that it tooks a lot of time to "update variables and the dom" after clicking on a button.

How can i improve performances?

Thanks a lot!

Edit: here is some code:

```
                                  <div class="row" ng-repeat="date in dateRanges track by date.value">

                                          <div ng-show="!date.custom" class="col-xs-14 col-sm-15 date-filter no-rel">
                                              <div class="button-container button-radio"><button data-ng-class="{'radiob disabled': getDate() != date,'radiob active': getDate() == date}" ng-click="setDate(date)"></button></div>
                                              <div class="button-container button-text">
                                                  <button class="select-date" ng-click="setDate(date)">{{date.title}} {{date.noDetails ? '' : date.start | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}} {{date.noDetails ? '' : '-'}} {{date.noDetails ? '' : date.end | date:'dd/MM/yyyy'}}</button>
                                              </div>
                                          </div>

                                          <div ng-if="date.custom" class="col-xs-2 col-sm-1 date-filter">
                                              <button data-ng-class="{'radiob disabled':getDate() != date,'radiob active':getDate() == date}" ng-click="setDate(date)"></button>
                                          </div>
                                          <div ng-if="date.custom" class="col-xs-14 col-sm-15 date-filter no-rel">
                                              <div class="row" data-ng-class="{'has-error': hasErrorComune && criteriRicerca_DateRange.custom}">
                                 </div>                

                                          <div class="col-md-16 mrg-t-10 text-center">
                                              <button id="Undo" ng-click="Undo()" class="btn btn-esci mrg-r-10">Undo</button>

                                              <button type="submit" id="dropdownMovimentiConferma" ng-click="Operation()" data-ng-disabled="criteriRicerca_DateRange.custom && (hasErrorComune || hasErrorStart || hasErrorEnd)" class="btn btn-primary">OK</button>


    </div>
```